# How to detect Mac OS version using Python?

Tags: python, macos

My application is assumed to be running on a Mac OS X system.  However, what I need to do is figure out what version of Mac OS (or Darwin) it is running on, preferably as a number.  For instance,

- "10.4.11" would return either 10.4 or 8
- "10.5.4" would return 10.5 or 9
- "10.6" would return 10.6 or 10

I found out that you could do this, which returns "8.11.0" on my system:

```
import os
os.system("uname -r")
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, or at least a way to pull the first number from the result?  Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.mac_ver()
('10.5.8', ('', '', ''), 'i386')
```

As you see, the first item of the tuple [`mac_ver`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html?highlight=mac_ver#platform.mac_ver) returns is a string, not a number (hard to make '10.5.8' into a number!-), but it's pretty easy to manipulate the `10.x.y` string into the kind of numbers you want.  For example,

```
>>> v, _, _ = platform.mac_ver()
>>> v = float('.'.join(v.split('.')[:2]))
>>> print v
10.5
```

If you prefer the Darwin kernel version rather than the MacOSX version, that's also easy to access -- use the similarly-formatted string that's the third item of the tuple returned by `platform.uname()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works on Debian (and probably other Linux) as well, giving false positives if you use this function to check if the system is Mac OS X

Comment: @RobertMoore [platform.system()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/platform.html#platform.system) should be used to detect the underlying OS rather than directly relying on `mac_ver()`

Comment: This does not work for Big Sur. `mac_ver()[0]` returns `10.16`, while I'm on 11.6.7. Of course, there is no 10.16 version, but 10.16 = 11 and no minor release info is provided. However, `mac_ver()[0]` does appear to work on Monterey, returning 12.4 on that system.

Answer (score 4):

If you are already using os, you might want to use os.uname()

```
import os
os.uname()
```

Comment: This gives the release version of Darwin itself -- for instance, Catalina is 19.6.0--it might be helpful in some contexts, but original poster is looking for the macOS version like 10.9

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the output of the /usr/bin/sw_vers command.

Comment: The uname command will give him the version - his problem is in how to get this value into a variable.

Comment: Well, at least it gives the kernel version - but he seems to have an overall problem of being able to read command output into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

platform.mac_ver() will return a  tuple (release, versioninfo, machine

So get mac version  by code

```
>>> platform.mac_ver()[0]

'10.8.4'
```

this method is easy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a command - like 'uname' - and get the results as a string, use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen(["uname", "-r"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```