# How to access OS name and version in Terminal or from inside my python code?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, operating-system, environment-variables

I want to have access to the OS name and Version from inside my Python code. Is there any environmental variable I can use for that purpose?

Note that I want to get the OS name and version that appears on the `About this mac` on my Mac. With `platform.uname()` I get different OS name and version!

Comment: But there is an issue, My OS name is "OS X Yosemite" and the version is "10.10.1" but what I get from `platform.uname()` or `os.uname()` is "Darwin" and "14.0.0" instead. What is the reason?

Comment: Then you're perhaps looking for [How to detect Mac OS version using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1777344)